# How to change the column name of a FK Id field?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

In my model, I have 2 many to many relationship to the same table. Like so:

```
public class BpsModel {
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Person> Reviewers { get; set; }
    public List<Person> Modelers { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

When I run migrations, this is the structure of the database Person table:

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "Persons",
    columns: table => new
    {
        Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
            .Annotation("Sqlite:Autoincrement", true),
        BpsModelId = table.Column<int>(nullable: true),
        BpsModelId1 = table.Column<int>(nullable: true),
        Email = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
        Name = table.Column<string>(nullable: true)
    },
    constraints: table =>
    {
        table.PrimaryKey("PK_Persons", x => x.Id);
        table.ForeignKey(
            name: "FK_Persons_BpsRecords_BpsModelId",
            column: x => x.BpsModelId,
            principalTable: "BpsRecords",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
        table.ForeignKey(
            name: "FK_Persons_BpsRecords_BpsModelId1",
            column: x => x.BpsModelId1,
            principalTable: "BpsRecords",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
    });
```

As you can see, the Person table has two columns with very similar names: `BpsModelId` and `BpsModelId1`. This is not helpful since I now have to go digging for which one is the Modeler and which one is the Reviewer.  Is there a way to change the column name to something like `ReviewerBpsModelId` and `ModelerBpsModelId`?

Thanks

Comment: Does this help? -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/columns -- HasColumnName() might be what you're looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `OnModelCreating` method you should set it by using fluent configuration like below:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<BpsModel>()
            .HasMany(p => p.Reviewers)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey("BpsModelReviewerId"); // <- You customize the foreign key name for Reviewers association

modelBuilder.Entity<BpsModel>()
            .HasMany(p => p.Modelers)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey("BpsModelModelerId"); // <- You customize the foreign key name for Modelers association
```

Comment: This is an option but wouldn't he need to use DataAnnotations?

Comment: @JohnOsborne If you use the attribute you're restricted to use the name of the properties that mus tbe  defined in Person entity. The actual code does not define foreign key properties for that. So you can't customize the foreign key columns names through data annotations.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a [KEY] to have a certain name in the database you can use DataAnnotations in your model class to configure the SQL Server column name. This is called [Column Mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/columns)

So you could do:

```
public class BpsModel {
    [Key]
    [Column("my_custom_column_name")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Person> Reviewers { get; set; }
    public List<Person> Modelers { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you need two Int fields, one to store the Modeler code and the other to the Reviewer, the problem is that the two keys are referenced by the same table. so do to solve the problem.

foreign key for Reviewer

```
[ForeignKey("ReviewerId")]
public int ReviewerId { get; set; }
public Person Reviewers { get; set; }
```

foreign key for Modeler

```
[ForeignKey("ModelerId")]
public int ModelerId { get; set; }
public Person Modelers { get; set; }
```

your class would look like this

```
public class BpsModel {
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ReviewerId")]
    public int ReviewerId { get; set; }
    public Person Reviewers { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ModelerId")]
    public int ModelerId { get; set; }
    public Person Modelers { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

   public ICollection<BpsModel> BpsModel{ get; set; }
}
```

add the using:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
```

Run Add-Migrations, It's Work in my projects!